# How to put 2 or more "id" in "for"?

Tags: html, css, forms, attributes

I need some help. The question is how to put in the "for" attribute two "id" parameters from input? or how a can do with label in other way?

```
<label for="address">Address: </label>
<input class="form-style" type="text" name="address" id="address"/>

<label for="gender1 gender2">Gender:</label>
<input class="gender" type="radio" name="gender" id="gender1" value="Male"/>Male
<input class="gender" type="radio" name="gender" id="gender2" value="Female"/>Female
```

Comment: You cannot associate a label element with more than one control

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. A label is for a single form control. Each radio button should have its own label.

Use a fieldset to group multiple controls, and a legend to describe the controls with it in.

```html
<label for="address">Address: </label>
<input class="form-style" type="text" name="address" id="address" />

<fieldset>
  <legend>Gender</legend>

  <input class="gender" type="radio" name="gender" id="gender1" value="Male" /> 
  <label for="gender1">Male</label>

  <input class="gender" type="radio" name="gender" id="gender2" value="Female" /> 
  <label for="gender2">Female</label>

  <input class="gender" type="radio" name="gender" id="gender3" value="Other" /> 
  <label for="gender3">Other</label>

  <input class="gender" type="radio" name="gender" id="gender4" value="Prefer not to say" /> 
  <label for="gender4">Prefer not to say</label>

</fieldset>
```